# How to append new rows to a gridview dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid view with some populated data. There are only three fields displayed from the below dataset. These are Jurisdiction - LicenseNumber - IssueDate.
Note that CommonJurisdictions field is just needed for programming purpose.

The dataset contains data like

========================================================================
CommonJurisdictions    -     Jurisdiction - LicenseNumber - IssueDate

Alabama,Alaska,New York  -     Alabama    -  123    -    1/4/2013

Alabama,Alaska,New York  -     Alaska    -   345    -     3/4/2012

Alabama,Alaska,New York  -     New York   -  678     -    4/5/2014

=========================================================================

I have a checkboxlist for jurisdictions in aspx page where user can select new set of jurisdictions and it is captured in a string variable Jurisdiction.

Now if user will select some more jurisdictions and it will be captured in string Jurisdiction like Alabama,Alaska,New York,California,Florida.

This string variable is passed as a parameter to a method like

```
    private void FillJurisdictionGrid(string Jurisdiction, string IssueDate)
    {

        LicenceBL lbl = new LicenceBL(0);
        DataSet lds = new DataSet();
        lbl.FetchForEdit(lds, LicenseType);
        string CommonJurisdictions = lds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CommonJurisdictions"].ToString();
       }
```

There is another variable string CommonJurisdictions which contain values like 
Alabama,Alaska,New York(values present in the above dataset). Now I want to compare CommonJurisdictions with Jurisdiction variable for checking whether there are some extra jurisdictions. In the above situation it will find that there are two extra jurisdictions California and Florida.Also let us suppose that IssueDate parameter contain date value like 12/12/2015. Now I want that Grid should be populated with data like below

========================================================================
Jurisdiction - LicenseNumber - IssueDate

Alabama    -  123    -    1/4/2013

Alaska    -   345    -     3/4/2012

New York   -  678     -    4/5/2014

California    -  null      -  12/12/2015

Florida    -  null      -  12/12/2015

=========================================================================

Can any one please help me how will i append these two rows dynamically on FillJurisdictionGrid() method... Actually this method is called on ok button clicked (when user will select jurisdictions from checkboxlist and click on ok button.

In aspx file grid view code is

```
               <asp:GridView ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0" runat="server" CssClass="table">
                            <Columns>


                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Non-Resident License">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblJurisdiction" runat="server" />
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>

                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Number">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseNumber" style="padding:12px 5px;" runat="server" />
                                       <br />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ValReqLN" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                                    ErrorMessage="License Number cannot be Blank." ControlToValidate="txtEffectiveDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" style="padding:12px 5px;" placeholder="(mm/dd/yyyy)" CssClass="datepiker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

The gridview is binded to data by below lines of code

```
        grdView.DataSource = lds.Tables[0].Select("Resident='No'"); ;
        grdView.DataBind();
        DataRow[] dtDummy = lds.Tables[0].Select("Resident='No'");
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
        {
            Label lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
            TextBox txtDateIssued = row.FindControl("txtEffectiveDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtDateExpiration = row.FindControl("txtExpirationDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtLicenseNumber = row.FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            if (dtDummy[row.RowIndex]["Resident"].ToString() == "No")
                {
                    lblJurisdiction.Text = dtDummy[row.RowIndex]["NRState"].ToString();
                    txtLicenseNumber.Text = dtDummy[row.RowIndex]["LicenceNumber"].ToString();
                    DateTime DI = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDummy[row.RowIndex]["DateIssued"]);
                    txtDateIssued.Text = DI.ToShortDateString(); 

                }

        }
```

Comment: On your `Ok` button click event handler filter the data which you want to append, add it to existing data and rebind the gridview. Adding it dynamically will add more complexity and you should avoid it.

Comment: can u please provide me simplie solution... i shall be highly thankful to u...

Comment: Hey I am not sure how its all working currently, exact code is really hard to answer. That's why I gave an idea. Do you know the structure of `lds.Tables[0].Select("Resident='No'")` datatable for example?

Comment: It is also a column in the dataset which Contains values like yes or no. I have omitted it in the question...

Comment: So are you binding juts one column to your gridview? `grdView.DataSource = lds.Tables[0].Select("Resident='No'"); ` shows this.

Comment: in the Gridview three fields are displayed Jurisdiction - LicenseNumber - IssueDate.

Comment: Basically I want to append rows dynamically to the already filled grid